# Enthalpy of the photon gas

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, photons, chemical-potential

> Find the enthalpy $H(S,p,N)$ of a the photon gas with state equations:
>
> $U = bVT^4$, where $b$ is a positive constant
>
> $p = \frac {U}{3V}$

Well, the wikipedia listed the enthalpy as $H = 4/3 U$ and the entropy as $S = \frac{4U}{3T}$ and the enthalpy is given as $H= U + pV$

Firstable, I tried to obtain the entropy:

$dS = (\frac {\partial S}{\partial U})dU + (\frac {\partial S}{\partial V})dV + (\frac {\partial S}{\partial N})dN$

$(\frac {\partial S}{\partial U}) = \frac {1}{T}$, $(\frac {\partial S}{\partial V}) = \frac {p}{T}$, $(\frac {\partial S}{\partial N}) = \frac {\mu}{T}$

$S(U,V,N)= \frac {4}{3}(bU^3V)^{1/4} + C$

I suppose the constant should be dependable on number of particles $N$, so $C=C(N)$, but following the Nernst's postulate (the entropy vanishes for $T \to 0$) this constant should be zero.

After all I got to the expression for the enthalpy in its natural variables as

$H(S,p) = S (\frac {3p}{b})^{1/4} [\frac {4}{3} + \frac {1}{4p}]$

I have no problem with my calculations as long as I avoid the number of particles (calculating the potential per particles). I am always stucked here. Like I read that the chemical potential of the photon gas (black body) is zero. And the number of particles isn't obtained in the state equations explicitly. So if I am asked to find $H(S,p,N)$, can it be expresed as $H(S,p)$? I literally don't know where to put that $N$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation are ok. You seem puzzled by the absence of $N$ dependence. It disapperas as soon as you correctly use the third principle to put $C(N)=0$.

A more transparent way of arriving to the same result is to recall that, due to extensiveness of entropy, the Euler equation holds:

$$
S = \frac{U}{T} + \frac{P}{T}V - \frac{\mu}{T}N.
$$
Moreover, from Gibbs-Duhem equation
$$
N d \left(\frac{\mu}{T}\right) = U d \left(\frac{1}{T}\right) +V d \left( \frac{P}{T} \right)
$$
but with the given equations of state $N d \left(\frac{\mu}{T}\right) =0$, which means $\left(\frac{\mu}{T}\right) = B =constant$.
Using the Euler equation, one arrives exactly to the same expression for $S$ you have obtained, with the function $C(N)=BN$. The third principle requires $B=0$.

Comment: Thank you, I think I am getting the intuition behind it. This example seemed tricky to me, but I have heard from my classmate that it is not possible in thermodynamics to obtain the number of particles in photon gas (or it is not trivial, using different field of physics), so I need to study it more.

Comment: And the entropy, volume and internal energy depend on $N$ anyway.

Comment: @Andromeda "volume and internal energy depend on N anyway." Not in this system. As you have derived, the N dependence disappears. so you have to stick to what you find: extensiveness requires that S depends on V and U but not on N. Similarly for the remaining thermodynamic functions. Of course, in the case of photons, one can introduce an average number pf photons of a given energy at equilibrium. But this quantity, easily obtained through statistical mechanics, does not play any role at the level of thermodynamics.